# awk: division by zero input record number 1, file source line number 1

Tags: shell, awk, statistics

Im trying to get the signed log10-transformed t-test P-value  by using the  sign of the log2FoldChange  multiplied by the inverse of the pvalue,

```
cat test.xlx | sort -k7g \
             | cut -d '_' -f2- \
             | awk '!arr[$1]++' \
             | awk '{OFS="\t"} 
               { if ($6>0) printf "%s\t%4.3e\n", $1, 1/$7; else printf "%s\t%4.3e\n", $1, -1/$7 }' \
             | sort -k2gr > result.txt
```

text.xls =

```
                   ID               baseMean    log2FoldChange  lfcSE   stat    pvalue  padj
        ENSMUSG00000037692-Ahdc1    2277.002091 1.742481553 0.170388822 10.22650154 1.51e-24    2.13e-20
        ENSMUSG00000035561-Aldh1b1  768.4504879 -2.325533089    0.248837002 -9.345608047    9.14e-21    6.45e-17
        ENSMUSG00000038932-Tcfl5    556.1693605 -3.742422892    0.402475728 -9.298505809    1.42e-20    6.71e-17
        ENSMUSG00000057182-Scn3a    1363.915962 1.621456045 0.175281852 9.250564289 2.23e-20    7.89e-17
        ENSMUSG00000038552-Fndc4    378.821132  2.544026087 0.288831276 8.808000721 1.27e-18    3.6e-15
```

but getting error awk: division by zero
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1

Comment: You need to avoid including the header record in your calculations. (Awk is trying to divide by `padj`, which is `$7` in the first row).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jas points out in a comment, you need to skip your header line but your script could stand some more cleanup than that. Try this:

```
sort -k7g test.xlx |
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
    { sub(/^[^_]+_/,"") }
    ($6~/[0-9]/) && (!seen[$1]++) { printf "%s\t%4.3e\n", $1, ($7?($6>0?1:-1)/$7:0) }
' |
sort -k2gr
ENSMUSG00000035561-Aldh1b1      1.550e+16
ENSMUSG00000037692-Ahdc1        4.695e+19
ENSMUSG00000038552-Fndc4        2.778e+14
ENSMUSG00000038932-Tcfl5        1.490e+16
ENSMUSG00000057182-Scn3a        1.267e+16
```

The above will print a result of zero instead of failing when $7 is zero.

What's the point of the `cut -d '_' -f2-` in your original script though (implemented above with `sub()`? You don't have any `_`s in your input file.